# Extract encoder and decoder from saved autoencoder

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I have saved models for a large number of autoencoders that I am using for my project. They were saved using the `autoencoder.save(outdir + "autoencoder_"+params)` function.

Is there any way for me to extract the encoder and decoder components of each of these saved models, or would I need to rerun the script and add in the `encoder = Model(input, bottleneck)` and `decoder = Model(bottleneck, output)` lines and save those models?

Here is the autoencoder structure I am attempting to retrieve:

```
autoencoder.summary()

Model: "model_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 3593, 4)]         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 14372)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1797)              25828281  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 719)               1292762   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 180)               129600    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 719)               130139    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 1797)              1293840   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 14372)             25840856  
_________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)            multiple                  0         
=================================================================
Total params: 54,515,478
Trainable params: 54,515,478
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer the weights to two different neural network models. All you need is to identify the index of the bottleneck layer which you can easily know by running `model.summary()`

Here is a snippet that can help you copy the model

```py
bottleneck_index = # this you need to identify
encoder_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
for layer in ae_model.layers[:bottleneck_index]:
    layer_config = layer.get_config()  # to get all layer's parameters (units, activation, etc...)
    copied_layer = type(layer).from_config(layer_config) # to initialize the same layer class with same parameters
    copied_layer.build(layer.input_shape)  # build the layer to initialize the weights.
    copied_layer.set_weights(layer.get_weights())  # transfer the trainable parameters
    encoder_model.add(copied_layer)  # add it to the encoder's model
```

Do the same for decoder, where `ae_model.layers[bottleneck_index:]`

Of course, you can even identify the bottleneck index by checking the units of current layers if it is smaller than the consecutive layer.

Comment: It's throwing me an error for the line `copied_layer.set_weights(layer.get_weights())`: ValueError: You called "set_weights(weights)" on layer "dense_2" with a weight list of length 2, but the layer was expecting 0 weights.

Comment: This is strange, it might failed because the layer didn't initialize the weights, I have updated my code to build layer before transferring the weights, can you give it a try?

Check line: `copied_layer.build(layer.input_shape)`

Comment: That does fix that issue, but now it is struggling with the reshape layer. I added the summary to the questions, seems like it could be helpful. Here's the error message: AttributeError: The layer "reshape has multiple inbound nodes, with different input shapes. Hence the notion of "input shape" is ill-defined for the layer. Use `get_input_shape_at(node_index)` instead.